# audio recording and POST to server

Tags: java, android

For starters i'm an Android newbie. I have an android application that records audio for 12 seconds to a raw file and then I use lame to convert it to the final file "mezzo.mp3". The application should then upload the file to a server. However, it seems the code never executes to the upload part. Here is my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
class UploadFileTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String responseString = "";
            try {
                String url = "http://178.62.209.46:8000/api/tag/";
                File track = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "mezzo.mp3");
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                MultipartEntityBuilder reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                reqEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                //InputStream inputStream = new ;
                reqEntity.addBinaryBody("track", track);
                final HttpEntity myEntity = reqEntity.build();
                httppost.setEntity(myEntity);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                //process response
                responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return responseString;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String responseString){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

and here is the timer and the UploadFileTask invocation:

```
Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartButton);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mRecMicToMp3.start();
                CountDownTimer countDowntimer = new CountDownTimer(12000, 1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        mRecMicToMp3.stop();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stopped recording Automatically ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }};countDowntimer.start();

            }
        });
        new UploadFileTask().execute();
```

The timer runs okay and the "Stopped recording Automatically " toast shows. However, it seems `new UploadFileTask().execute();`never runs.

What mistake i'm I making??

Comment: What does your log show? Do you have internet permissions in your manifest? Additionally, what do you mean the code never executes? Which part stops working?

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stopped recording Automatically ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`. Are you seeing that toast?
 `

Comment: the Toast is displayed after 12 seconds as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted way to much code. You are supposed to post only relevant code. That in onClick would have been sufficient.

You have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. This will also be clearly visible in the LogCat. You have to put the 'internet code' in an AsyncTask or Thread.

Update: Hmmmm... mayby i talked to soon. Honestly i do not know if code in 'onFinish' is executed on the main thread. But if the Toast comes through it is. Please look in the LogCat for real errors.

Comment: That is not enough logcat. I think there will be more to see. And if that toast comes through you will have the network on main thread exeption. And you know already what you have to do then.

Comment: I updated the code to use AsyncTask...however, it seems like it does not get to execute.

Comment: Remove the Toast from doInBackground. You cannot use a Toast there. Make Log.d() statements instead. You can use a Toast in onPostExecute to signal the end.

Comment: I think the AsyncTask is not returning, because every time I restart the process it returns the previous result. How do I ensure it is returning?

Comment: Asynctasks do not return a result. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: The network operation takes place after I close the app and open it again.

Comment: Should i understand where you are talking about?

Comment: Okay...When I click on the button, the audio is recorded for 12 seconds as expected. I expect the recorded file to be uploaded to the API immediately after that and get a response. However, the file is never uploaded when I let the application continue running...it only gets uploaded and gets a response when I close the app and open it again.

Answer (score 1):

You are starting your asynctask at the moment you install an onclicklistener. So even before the user has clicked. You should start it when the recording is done. Place that line directly after the toast that tells that the recording is stopped.